# When using semicolon for two ind.clauses, does parenthetical citation apply to the full sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

I have a technical question.

In the following sentence, the in-text citation in parenthetical needs to be applied to the whole sentence. I am not sure if a semicolon separating the two clauses makes the citation apply itself to only the second clause.

> But the regional unemployment rate is not an appropriate indicator of an individual’s employment prospects; and differentiating access, benefit duration, and benefit amount on the basis of the regional unemployment rate is, in fact, quite problematic (XX 2009; YY 2011).

I am following Chicago Manual of Style, but can't find any reference there to such a query.

Comment: If it's an in-text citation, it doesn't need to apply only to a single sentence. You can quote an entire paragraph, with multiple sentence, and the citation would apply to it in its entirety. So long as it's clear in context that you are referencing the entire thing (of however many sentences), there is no problem. To make that clear, you can indent a block quote.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question about English language and usage, but about the conventions of referencing. It may belong on writers.stackexchange.

Comment: @ColinFine is right, but the major problem with the sentence is that it is very hard on the reader. Consider what it is that in the second clause is "quite problematic" Answer: a very very long noun clause composed of complex ideas expressed in polysyllabic words. You would answer your question about placing the references if you were more precise about which ideas in particular those references support.

Comment: In general, a citation will refer to **the portion of the text that requires external validation**.  As long as the text refers to the same overall  concept, it can be a part of a sentence, multiple sentences, or an entire paragraph.  Once the text references a different concept, it normally requires a separate citation.